# ejabberd - Fetch the history messages mod_mam via API

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-api

I've activated mod_mam module in Ejabberd as follow:-

```
mod_mam:
    db_type: sql
    assume_mam_usage: true
    default: always
    clear_archive_on_room_destroy: false
```

How do I fetch messages over the APIs?

Answer (score 0):

If "over the APIs" means using mod_http_api, xmlrpc, ReST, or similar, then that isn't possible. mod_mam right now is to be used by XMPP clients as defined in https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html

Comment: Can you pls provide your valuable suggestions on this question too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61396406/ejabberd-run-sql-query-for-custom-command