# Ejabberd - Run SQL Query for Custom Command

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-api

I'm trying to make a custom command in `mod_admin_extra.erl`. to fetch messages between 2 JIDs.

My command will look like this:-

```
ejabberdctl get_messages HOST FROM TO START_TIME END_TIME
```

The SQL query will be like:-

```
select * from archive where (username = FROM and bare_peer = TO) OR (username=TO and bare_peer = FROM) where created_at BETWEEN START_TIME AND END_TIME;
```

I went through [this](https://www.ejabberd.im/forum/25028/solved-how-configure-and-test-modmam-message-archive-management/index.html) thread to understand how IQ query works and want to build a similar sort of a thing via the command and API.

**How do I fire the query in the above function so as to fetch the messages between the conversations of 2 JIDs??**

My response would be a list of dictionaries:-

```
[{from: jid1, to: jid2, body: Hello, created_at: T1}]
```

I would be in turn using the same command for the POST API to fetch messages.

**UPDATE**

As per the suggestion provided by @Badlop, I updated my function with

```
 % ----------------- Custom Command Get Message ----------------------
 #ejabberd_commands{name = get_message, tags = [stanza],
        desc = "Get messages from a local or remote bare of full JID",
        longdesc = "Get messages of a specific JID sent to a JID",
        module = ?MODULE, function = get_message,
        args = [{host, binary}, {from, binary}, {to, binary},
            {start_time, binary}, {end_time, binary}],
        args_example = [<<"localhost">>, <<"admin">>, <<"user1">>,
            <<"2015-07-00T00:00:00Z">>, <<"2015-07-029T13:23:54Z">>],
        args_desc = ["Host", "From JID", "Receiver JID", "Start Time", "End Time"],
        result = {result, {
                    tuple, [{messages, list, {message, {tuple,
                    [
                       {timestamp, string},
                       {xml, string},
                       {txt, string},
                       {peer, integer},
                       {kind, integer},
                       {nick, string}
                    ]}}},
                  {status, string},
                  {count, integer}]}}
        },
 % ----------------- Custom Command Ends -----------------------------
```

This is my function that gets called when the command is received.

```
% ----------------- Custom Function Get Message ----------------------
get_message(Host, From, To, StartTime, EndTime) ->
    mod_mam:select(
        Host,
        jid:make(From, Host),
        jid:make(From, Host),
        [{start, xmpp_util:decode_timestamp(StartTime)},
         {'end', xmpp_util:decode_timestamp(EndTime)},
         {with, jid:make(To, Host)}],
        #rsm_set{},
        chat,
        all
    ).
% ----------------- Custom Function Get Message ----------------------
```

However, it returns an error response:-

```
Unhandled exception occurred executing the command:
** exception error: no function clause matching
                  ejabberd_ctl:format_result([],
                                             {messages,list,
                                              {message,
                                               {tuple,
                                                [{timestamp,string},
                                                 {xml,string},
                                                 {peer,integer},
                                                 {kind,integer},
                                                 {nick,string}]}}}) (src/ejabberd_ctl.erl, line 405)
   in function  ejabberd_ctl:format_result/2 (src/ejabberd_ctl.erl, line 461)
   in call from ejabberd_ctl:try_call_command/4 (src/ejabberd_ctl.erl, line 321)
   in call from ejabberd_ctl:process2/4 (src/ejabberd_ctl.erl, line 274)
   in call from ejabberd_ctl:process/2 (src/ejabberd_ctl.erl, line 252)
   in call from rpc:'-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-'/5 (rpc.erl, line 197)
```

The query printed in the logs in as follow:-

```
2020-04-24 21:57:13.717746+05:30 [debug] SQL: "SELECT  timestamp, xml, peer, kind, nick FROM archive WHERE username=E'admin' and server_host=E'localhost' and bare_peer=E'test@localhost' and timestamp >= 1587692943312536 and timestamp <= 1587779343312536 ORDER BY timestamp ASC ;"
2020-04-24 21:57:13.726745+05:30 [debug] SQL: "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM archive WHERE  username=E'admin' and server_host=E'localhost' and bare_peer=E'test@localhost' and timestamp >= 1587692943312536 and timestamp <= 1587779343312536;"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is database independent:

```
mod_mam:select(
    <<"localhost">>,
    jid:make(<<"user1">>, <<"localhost">>),
    jid:make(<<"user1">>, <<"localhost">>),
    [{start, xmpp_util:decode_timestamp(<<"2020-04-24T14:37:25Z">>)},
     {'end', xmpp_util:decode_timestamp(<<"2020-04-24T14:37:30Z">>)},
     {with, jid:make(<<"user2">>,<<"localhost">>)}],
    #rsm_set{},
    chat,
    all
).
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it returns an error. It seems I'm close and yet so far. I've updated the question with the error and the steps followed. Please have a look.

Comment: Any suggestion @Badlop? Your help is highly appreciated!!

Comment: I looked into the code a bit more and I believe its because of the formatting error. I've updated my formatting, but still not able to return the response properly. Pls have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Umm, you were still far away, the command result was wrong, and the call result must be processed. what about this?

```
$ ejabberdctl get_mam_messages user1@localhost user2@localhost 2020-04-27T00:00:00Z 2020-04-27T23:59:59Z
```

Required patch:

```
diff --git a/src/mod_mam.erl b/src/mod_mam.erl
index 08a4059b4..d2d74913c 100644
--- a/src/mod_mam.erl
+++ b/src/mod_mam.erl
@@ -42,6 +42,7 @@
     get_room_config/4, set_room_option/3, offline_message/1, export/1,
     mod_options/1, remove_mam_for_user_with_peer/3, remove_mam_for_user/2,
     is_empty_for_user/2, is_empty_for_room/3, check_create_room/4,
+    get_messages_command/4,
     process_iq/3, store_mam_message/7, make_id/0, wrap_as_mucsub/2, select/7]).

 -include("xmpp.hrl").
@@ -1355,8 +1356,29 @@ get_jids(undefined) ->
 get_jids(Js) ->
     [jid:tolower(jid:remove_resource(J)) || J <- Js].

+get_messages_command(From, To, StartTime, EndTime) ->
+    FromJid = jid:decode(From),
+    {Stanzas, _, _} =
+   mod_mam:select(
+     FromJid#jid.lserver, FromJid, FromJid,
+     [{start, xmpp_util:decode_timestamp(StartTime)},
+      {'end', xmpp_util:decode_timestamp(EndTime)},
+      {with, jid:decode(To)}],
+     #rsm_set{}, chat, all),
+    [fxml:element_to_binary(xmpp:encode(Subels))
+     || {_, _, #forwarded{sub_els = [Subels]}} <- Stanzas].
+
 get_commands_spec() ->
-    [#ejabberd_commands{name = delete_old_mam_messages, tags = [purge],
+    [#ejabberd_commands{
+   name = get_mam_messages, tags = [mam],
+   desc = "Get archived messages of an account with another contact",
+   module = ?MODULE, function = get_messages_command,
+   args = [{from, binary}, {to, binary}, {start, binary}, {'end', binary}],
+   args_example = [<<"user1@localhost">>, <<"user2@example.org">>,
+           <<"2020-04-27T00:00:00Z">>, <<"2020-04-27T23:59:59Z">>],
+   args_desc = ["Local JID", "Contact JID", "Start Time", "End Time"],
+   result = {messages, {list, {message, string}}}},
+     #ejabberd_commands{name = delete_old_mam_messages, tags = [purge],
            desc = "Delete MAM messages older than DAYS",
            longdesc = "Valid message TYPEs: "
                   "\"chat\", \"groupchat\", \"all\".",
```